# Rewriting a lagrangian in terms of Hodge duals?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, tensor-calculus

Spinors have been found to have some interesting applications in general relativity (such as Wittens positive energy proof). Recently I'd come across a series of papers [1](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.60.021501) [2](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02107951) [3](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0218271807010900) (there are many more papers) utilizing a “quadratic spinor lagrangian” for General relativity, which is equivalent to the tetrad formulation of GR. The Lagrangian goes like:

$$S=\intop2D\bar{\Psi}\gamma_{5}D\Psi$$ Where $\Psi$ is a spinor valued 1-form $\Psi=\theta\psi$ , $\theta=\gamma_{\alpha}\theta^{\alpha}$ is an orthonormal frame 1-form and $\psi$ is a spinor field. We're here using the derivative $D\Psi=d\Psi+\omega\Psi$, where $\omega=\frac{1}{4}\gamma_{\alpha\beta}\omega^{\alpha\beta}$. Through a spinor curvature identity it is shown that the normalization condition $\bar{\psi}\psi=1$ renders the action equivalent to the Einstein Hilbert action (up to a boundary term that doesn't enter the equations of motion).

I've been trying to rewrite this lagrangian in terms of Hodge duals, but for some reason I've been unable to figure it out. I keep ending up with something like:

$$S=\intop2D\bar{\Psi}*\left(D\Psi\right)$$

I'm well aware my differential forms need some work, but how would I go about writing the original lagrangian in terms of Duals?

NOTE: The authors use of "Clifform notation" generally omits the wedge symbol in their equations. Also, trying to tag this under differential forms refers me to the "tensor calculus" tag for some reason.

Comment: Non-paywalled versions of the papers cited: https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9809030 https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9407004 https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0703076

Comment: FYI, the papers you cited invoked an extra condition on the spinor: $\bar{\psi}\gamma_5\psi=0$ in addition to the normalization $\bar{\psi}\psi=1$. And for that matter, what about $\bar{\psi}\gamma_{\mu}\psi$ or $\bar{\psi}\gamma_{\mu}\gamma_{\nu}\psi$?

Comment: @A.V.S.   Here is probably the clearest paper on this lagrangian, which expresses the equation in terms of both Dirac and Weyl spinor fields https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9502037.pdf

Comment: @MadMax        As far as the other terms you mention above, it seems like they would have to represent some kind of current flow, which may or may not be conserved, analogously to currents and axial currents in QFT.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit leery about the formalism in the paper you cited. Since conditions are imposed on the spinor
$$
\bar{\psi}\psi=1, \\
\bar{\psi}\gamma_5\psi=0,
$$ 
are you supposed to add extra constraint terms like
$$
\lambda(\bar{\psi}\psi -1) + \lambda'\bar{\psi}\gamma_5\psi,
$$
into the proposed the Lagrangian?

Comment: This paper, makes use of a more explicit notation, which clarifies the situation I believe: https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9502037.pdf   To my knowledge no such terms are needed.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your interest. I'm not entirely sure that I understand your question. I don't need to add a constraint term to the Einstein-Hilbert lagrangian of the form:

$$\lambda(g^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\nu}-1)$$

just because we have the requirement that $g^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\nu}=1$. Anyway, I'm just trying to write the initial lagrangian in terms of the Hodge dual.

Comment: @R.Rankin, by definition $\bar{\psi} = {\psi}^{\dagger}\gamma_0$, and we don't need constraint term such as $\lambda(\bar{\psi} - {\psi}^{\dagger}\gamma_0)$. This case is similar to your $g^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\nu}=1$. However, $\bar{\psi}\psi=1$ is a different animal. It is imposed by fiat.

Comment: Take a look at the paper in my first comment to your  answer, they start witth the (chiral) EH lagrangian and go from there. they reference the normalized (weyl here) spinors as simply being spin frames and reference Penrose/Rindler's two wonderful volumes on the subject (which I happen to own and so looked that up and it all seems pretty straight forward the spin frames are by definition normalized). anyway, I'm just trying to figure out how to write the lagrangian in terms of Hodge duals.

Comment: In https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9502037.pdf  The paragraphs surrounding equations 21 and 22 in essence say that the two constraints you mention are entirely equivalent to A. taking the metric to be real, and B. taking the metric to be "normalized" to one as I mention above as an example of a definition in Riemannian geometry. While I appreciate your answer, it doesn't address my question in the slightest.

Comment: Wouldn't that first condition just correspond to an orthonormalized spin basis?   Then we're essentially saying that were choosing everywhere orthonormal spinors. That approach is certainly no problem for vectorial/1-form valued basis